# how to store discord userid using python 3

Tags: discord.py, python-3.8

I'm trying to create a discord bot that could have the option to ban people forever. That means that even if someone unbanned him he will be banned again.

I'm trying to do that with a file that will save the userid but the problem is that the userid is not a string and I can't save it in a file.. but still if I can save it as str and convert it to integer it's not the problem.

My code is:

> ```
> @client.command()
> @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
> async def testban(bot):
>     member = client.get_user(int(460688177846550528))
>     await member.ban(reason='this is a test')
> ```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Discord's [User.id](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.id) is an `int`. To write it to a file you can simply convert it to a `str`:

```
str(userId)
```

When reading it, you can convert it back to an int:

```
int(userIdStr)
```

The User object can then be retrieved using [Client.get_user()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user)

Comment: but the problem is that you can't type:
```member = int(userId)
await member.ban(reason=<reason>)
```

Comment: Use [Client.get_user()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user) for this